# javascript .style property of span tag in anchor tag not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I am trying to style some buttons for my website

**This is my html**

```
<div>
    <a class="page_numbers"><span>100</span></a>
    <a class="page_numbers"><span>2</a></span></div>
```

**this is my css**

```
.page_numbers{
    display:table-cell;
    border:solid;
    padding:0px;
    border-radius:100px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;

}
div {
    display:table;
    border-spacing:10px;
}
}
```

**and finally this is my javascript**

```
var obj=document.getElementsByClassName("page_numbers")
for (i in obj){
 console.log(obj[i].children)
 obj[i].children[0].style.color="black"
 obj[i].style.borderColor="rgb(85,170,255)"
 function jun(i){
 obj[i].addEventListener('mouseenter',function(){obj[i].style.background="yellow";obj[i].style.color="red"},true)
//
obj[i].addEventListener('mouseleave',function(){
    obj[i].style.background="white";
    obj[i].style.color="rgb(12,31,22)";},true)
}
    jun(i);
}
```

the background color changes on mouseleave and enter **but not the font color**...I suppose I am doing something wrong along the way or I am missing a fundamental concept

**this is my jsfiddle link**

**`http://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/boqv8hak/`**

advice please..still learning JS

Comment: Looks like you are setting the color on the a tag instead of the span tag on mouseleave

Comment: hmm...but will the children elements not inherit the parent's property?...just a thought

Comment: No, because you already have the black colored on the span tag which is more specific than the red on the a tag. CSS specificity would rule in favor of the black span color.

Comment: Just  a comment to possibly prevent future problems shouldn't your closing span tag be inside of your a tag

Comment: @Binvention..glad you notice this...I'll make the correction in my official html page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, all of this should be in CSS and is trivial to do so

```
.page_numbers:hover
{
    background-color: yellow;
}

.page_numbers:hover span
{
    color: red;
}
```

Now the issue you are having is that on about the 4th line of your JS you explicitly set the color of the child element (the span) inside the .page_number element to be black. Now on you mouse enter you are setting the color on the page_number element, but since the child has a style applied directly to it (i.e. color: black) it does not inherit the parent style. Inline styles (i.e. style applied directly to the element with the style="" attribute, which is what JS does) always have the highest precedence. This is why it is generally not best practice to put inline styles on an element, as you have just seen, they are pretty much impossible to override. So change either the child to not have an explicit style, or on the mouse enter change the child not the parent

```
var obj = document.getElementsByClassName("page_numbers")
for (i in obj) {
    console.log(obj[i].children)
    obj[i].children[0].style.color = "black"
    obj[i].style.borderColor = "rgb(85,170,255)"
    function jun(i) {
        obj[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
            obj[i].style.background = "yellow";
            obj[i].children[0].style.color = "red"
        }, true)
        //
        obj[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
            obj[i].style.background = "white";
            obj[i].children[0].style.color = "rgb(12,31,22)";
        }, true)
    }
    jun(i);
}
```

or

```
var obj = document.getElementsByClassName("page_numbers")
for (i in obj) {
    console.log(obj[i].children)
    obj[i].style.borderColor = "rgb(85,170,255)"
    function jun(i) {
        obj[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
            obj[i].style.background = "yellow";
            obj[i].style.color = "red"
        }, true)
        //
        obj[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
            obj[i].style.background = "white";
            obj[i].style.color = "rgb(12,31,22)";
        }, true)
    }
    jun(i);
}
```

but as I indicated all this should really be in CSS

Comment: I suppose I went a little too much on the mixture of javascript and css..I was just testing..my css skills....:D

Answer (score 1):

You trying to change color of `a` instead of `span`

Try like this

```
obj[i].children[0].style.color = "red"
```

<kbd>**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/boqv8hak/1/)**</kbd>